# How to add &post_type=product on woocommerce url search results

Tags: woocommerce, woocommerce-theming

I have a theme form yootheme pro and i have on searchform.php the code below:

```html
<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying a search form.
 */

$result = get_view('search', [

    'position' => get_current_sidebar(),
    'attrs' => [

        'id' => 'search-'.rand(100, 999),
        'action' => esc_url(home_url('/')),
        'method' => 'get',
        'role' => 'search',
        'class' => '',

    ],
    'fields' => [

        ['tag' => 'input', 'name' => 's', 'placeholder' => esc_attr_x('Search &hellip;', 'placeholder'), 'value' => get_search_query()], 'name' => get_post_type()]

    ]

]);

if ($echo) {
    echo $result;
} else {
    return $result;
}
```

I kneed to modify this coded and add to result url the &post_type=product

thanks

Comment: Do you only want products within your search? or pages and posts and all the stuff too?

Comment: Yes only products!

The url after search is: https://www.example.com/?s=test (this with code below)

and i kneed to be: https://www.example.com/?s=test&post_type=product (this with modify code) 

Thanks

Comment: And if you only want products, you just need the post_type GET parameter in the URL

Answer (score 0):

Try this out. Not sure if this works in your template but in mine it does. So just for clarification: There are many different post types in WordPress. For example page, product usw...

What we do know is to tell the function which kind of search values it should take. Logically it should work!

```html
<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying a search form.
 */

$result = get_view('search', [

    'position' => get_current_sidebar(),
    'attrs' => [

        'id' => 'search-'.rand(100, 999),
        'action' => esc_url(home_url('/')),
        'method' => 'get',
        'role' => 'search',
        'class' => '',

    ],
    'fields' => [

        ['tag' => 'input', 'name' => 's', 'placeholder' => esc_attr_x('Search &hellip;', 'placeholder'), 'value' => 'product'], 'name' => 'post_type']

    ]

]);

if ($echo) {
    echo $result;
} else {
    return $result;
}
```